# Try to Build Unity game in XCode: ID 34411 Error duplicate symbols for architecture arm64\

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, build

I try to Run my Unity Application on my Iphone 12.

Every time i Build the Project in XCODE, i get the Error "ID 34411 Error duplicate symbols for architecture arm64".

You can download my Stacktrace here:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2c699c06fd310674e8b78995e46ff7a320210705110141/849b86cbbdee1ecc34b985bb915f178320210705110156/7439a3

I would upload it directly but it have 120k lines.

All the files mentioned in the Stack trace are in a folder called amd64.

I tried to delete the complete folder but it is automatically created again when building the project in XCODE. Even after some googling I didn't get any further. Since I am new to Unity / Xcode, I would need help here.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to delete a *different* folder. Seems like you have 2 complete DLLs imported into the project. You should find the other one and delete that one instead (make a backup first).

Let the one created automatically by Unity be the only one to exist.